# use NSArray to get minimum and maximum values of objects

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsarray, ios5

I have an NSArray of double objects.... I currently I have a for loop to go through the NSArray and average them. I am looking for a way to determine the minimum and maximum values in the NSArray and have no idea where to start... below is the current code I have to get the average.

```
NSArray *TheArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects];
    int TotalVisitors = [TheArray count];
    double aveRatingSacore = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < TotalVisitors; i++)
        {
            Visitor *object = [TheArray objectAtIndex:i];
            double two = [object.rating doubleValue];
            aveRatingSacore = aveRatingSacore + two;
        }

        aveRatingSacore = aveRatingSacore/TotalVisitors;
```

Any help, suggestions or code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some friendly notes on style, offered in good nature: 1. the first line creates an unnecessary array. You can simply set theArray to the return of fetchedObjects. 2. The last line in your loop can use the unary assignment operator: aveRatingScore += two; 3. Check out Objective-C "fast enumeration". With all this your entire loop could be one line: aveRatingScore += [object.rating doubleValue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup two doubles, one for min, one for max. Then in each iteration, set each to the min/max of the existing min/max and the current object in the iteration.

```
double theMin;
double theMax;
BOOL firstTime = YES;
for(Visitor *object in TheArray) {
  if(firstTime) {
    theMin = theMax = [object.rating doubleValue];
    firstTime = NO;
    coninue;
  }
  theMin = fmin(theMin, [object.rating doubleValue]);
  theMax = fmax(theMax, [object.rating doubleValue]);
}
```

The firstTime bit is only to avoid false-positives involving zero.

Answer (score 12):

What about this?

```
NSArray *fetchedObjects = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;
double avg = [[fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath: @"@avg.price"] doubleValue];
double min = [[fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath: @"@min.price"] doubleValue];
double max = [[fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath: @"@max.price"] doubleValue];
```

Comment: your code was resulting in a crash (valueForKey:), I have updated it to valueForKeyPath.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray *TheArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects];
int TotalVisitors = [TheArray count];
double aveRatingSacore = 0;
double minScore = 0;
double maxScore = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < TotalVisitors; i++)
        { 
            Visitor *object = [TheArray objectAtIndex:i];
            double two = [object.rating doubleValue];
            aveRatingSacore = aveRatingSacore + two;
            if (i == 0) {
                minScore = two;
                maxScore = two;
                continue;
            }
            if (two < minScore) {
                 minScore = two;
            }
            if (two > maxScore) {
                 maxScore = two;
            }
        }

aveRatingSacore = aveRatingSacore/TotalVisitors;
```